# Пересборка Map Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

Есть исходный Map.

```
Map<String, ComplexObject> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Как собрать из этой Map, вот эту:

```
Map<String, List<ComplexObject>>
```

Одна из тщетных попыток:

```
Map<String,List<ComplexObject>> test2 = map.entrySet().
                stream().
                collect(Collectors.toMap(ComplexObject::getName, map.values().stream().toList()))
```

Решение:

```
Map<String,List<ComplexObject>> test2 = map.values().
            stream().
            collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ComplexObject::getName,Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Что должно являться ключом в новой мапе? По какому принципу должен формироваться `List<ComplexObject>`?

Comment: @МихаилМуругов забыл отметить, ключом в новой мапе должно быть поле name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Map<String, List<ComplexObject>> test2 = map.values()
   .stream()
   .collect(groupingBy(ComplexObject::getName, toList()));
```

Comment: Поражаюсь, как жависты умеют читать мысли :)

Comment: @МихаилМуругов слишком часто мне приходится писать что-то подобное)

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko немного другой синтаксис) обновил топик)